# How to show ViewPager below of Toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-bottomnav

I want show some `Fragments` in my application and for this I want show `viewPager` and `BottomNavigation`. 
I want show this `viewPager` below of `Toolbar`, I write below codes but not work me and not show `toolbar`!
**MainPage codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.nouri.sevenwatchlist.Activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigationViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainToolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:selectedBackgroundVisible="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use this code into `viewPager`,         `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` but not work me again!

How can I fix it? Please help me

Comment: any example of which type of layout you want to make?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar, can you help me and send to me code? please I need this please

Comment: first show me any image which type u want to make, then i will write code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove following property from viewpager and check

```
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Comment: :D it's very crazy issue :D . I'm nerves and not see this. thanks my friend

Comment: Welcome buddy.. :)